# Unable to knit pdf from Rmardown from Rstudio in Windows 10 PC

Tags: latex, rstudio, knitr

I created a new Rmd file in the latest R and Rstudio version, and with the complete version of MiKTeX installed. In my windows 10 machine.

When I tried to knit it I got the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `fancyvrb.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.34 \newcommand

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Además: Warning message:
comando ejecutado '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS pdfprueba.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pdfprueba.pdf --template "C:\Users\karin\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' tiene estatus 43
```

Ejecución interrumpida

I suspected that it could have been that I didn't have the package fancyvrb in MiKTeX , so I followed [these](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) instructions but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the same using

```
Miktex package manager (admin)
```

Under > repository check that your package repository is up to date.
In the name box type the name of your package
Then filter
then add your package
[image: adding fancyvrb to miktex]

To test if your package is installed in dos CMD type
kpsewhich fancyvrb.sty. you should be able to see the path to your package.

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.
C:\>kpsewhich fancyvrb.sty
C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
```