# Package pdftex.def Error: File not found: using draft setting

Tags: windows, r-markdown, jpeg

The Rmd is not rendered although rendering is fine with html! There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099813/error-generating-pdf-with-rmarkdown), but it is not answered. The jpg is also located in a local directory, as latex cannot handle `http//` paths

Here is a reproducible example (The picture exists and rendering is ok in html mode):

````
---
title: 'Title'
author: "SQC"
date: "30 march 2019"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Some text.

![text](C:/path2/file.jpg){width=500px}

more text...
````

**Comment**: As suggested in the linked answer, I added

````
```{r}
getwd()
list.files("C:/path2/", full.names=TRUE)
```
````

Then the error is

> "C:/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to
>   latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output test.tex --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template "C:\R\R-3.5.1\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex"
>   --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable
>   "compact-title:yes"  output file: test.knit.md
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `fancyvrb.sty' not found.
>
> ! Emergency stop.
>
> Fehler: Failed to compile test.tex. See test.log for more info.
>   Ausführung angehalten

Again, I know from redering the html, that everything is ok: path exists, file exists and is listed.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/359 You have to install some additional latex packages.

Comment: @J_F I don't want to change my running miktex right now. But there might be another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47621867/5784831). Unfortunately, this does not work right now: `parse error - unexpected end of input; expected '}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the "solution" was simple: I just had to change the path for packages as suggested e.g. [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2552/#48b4).

=> Run "miktex-console_admin.exe"
=> Go to Packages => Install from... I also changed to Uni-Hagen.

PS: I don't know whether it was essential to work on a windows machine.